# ANE for one platform on Flex mobile project for iOS and Android

Tags: flex-mobile, air-native-extension

I'm very new at Flex Mobile Projects and native extension.

I have a big doubt... If I have an ANE that only works on iOS or Android, can I use it into a project for Android AND iOS?

I mean, if I want to do something and I've only found and ANE that works for iOS and another ANE that works for Android, can I create only one project and depending on the device use one or another? or should I create two different projects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to correctly code using two different ANE's, one for each platform, but it does really depend on the ANE.

Most provide a isSupported flag to allow you to determine programmatically whether the extension is supported on the current platform.

```
if (ExtensionA.isSupported)
{
    // Use extension A
}
else if (ExtensionB.isSupported)
{
    // Use extension B
}
```

It's also worth noting that if the extension isn't correctly implementing a "default" version (i.e. one that gets used on unsupported platforms) this may fail. Really comes down to the ANE implementation.

Comment: I'm unable to add an ANE only for IOS on Flex Mobile project for Android and IOS. It says: This ANE does not support  Google Android platform. What it's correct...

Comment: If an ANE is correctly implemented, when you get this message, the packager should use the "default" implementation of the ANE, which should hopefully implement the isSupported function and return false so you can use the above code snippet. 

If not, unfortunately you may not be able to use a single code base.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with an ANE that doesn't have a default implementation. This is the reason that I can't support it. Thanks for your help.